# What happens when \textheight changes mid-document?

Tags: page-breaking, margins

I know it's generally considered to be unwise, but I need to understand what happens when `\textheight` changes mid-document. From this example, it appears that the change takes effect on the *next* page, when `\vsize` is changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\typeout{Page 1:}
\showthe\textheight
\showthe\vsize
abc
\newpage
\typeout{Page 2:}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}
\showthe\textheight
\showthe\vsize
def
\newpage
\typeout{Page 3:}
\showthe\textheight
\showthe\vsize
ghi
\end{document}
```

Is this always the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not "unwise" to change `\textheight` in mid-document - it is unsupported and by changing it midway strange things can happen. On the whole you are right, if you  do this then it appears to affect the next page, but there are dependencies to the float algorithm which are asynchronous to the pages (for example, a float is tested when encountered to ensure that it doesn't exceed `\textheight`, and if so it will get artificially shortened so that the float algorithm can expect that all floats fit onto the page).

But there are also other surprising side-effects: try out this example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\textheight{4\baselineskip}\addtolength\textheight{\topskip}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure*}  X\\Y \end{figure*}  %  <--- uncomment for test and watch what happens to page 2

1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9 \newpage

\addtolength\textheight{-3\baselineskip}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here is what you get with and without the float on page 2 (the height reduction happens only from page 3 onwards):

[image]

But with the float already the second page gets shortened but has too much material now:
[image]

Now this is something one could argue is a LaTeX 2e (or even LaTeX2.09) bug, but then one could call it a feature as it is unsupported input.

In summary, if you *need* to understand what's really going on because you want to build something that changes `\textheight` then I fear you need to study all the places where it is being used

```
grep textheight latex.ltx
grep @colht latex.ltx
```

and whether what happens there can effect what you are trying to do --- but as I said it is not a supported interface variable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I _don't_ want to build something that changes `\textheight` mid-document, but the [exam document class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) does so if `\extraheadheight` is used with an optional argument that changes the header size on the first page. I considered trying to debug its behaviour, but now I have decided to avoid this feature instead.

Comment: @Ian don't know what the exam class does here and right now can't check, but for something like the first page using `\enlargethispage` might be safer.

Answer (score 16):

`\textheight` is also consulted at various points in the float placement algorithm.
This is why the `lscape` package (which changes `\textheight` of course) does a `\clearpage` when switching size. If a float floats from the point at which it decided it needed to float, to a point where `\textheight` is different, the effects must be deterministic, but they are probably all bad....

It's probably worth noting that for temporary changes to the page height the `\enlargethispage` command is the supported interface, and it's not exactly a coincidence that this is essentially implemented using a hidden internal float, and doesn't change `\textheight`.

Answer (score 8):

`\textheight` does take effect only after the current page ends.

if you really need to change the height of the current page, `\enlargethispage` is what you want.  however, i have no idea what would happen if you intend the page to be occupied by a full-length float, or even if you want to allow a just slightly-too-large "regular" float to coexist on the current page with some text.  (david can probably address that if you insist.)

it's probably worth mentioning that the effect of `enlargethispage` vanishes after the current page is output.  it's not intended to persist for the remainder of the document.

Comment: well, *most* of what is affected happens only after the current page ends. But unfortunately it isn't a clean situation as I explained and showed in my answer.

Comment: thanks, @Frank, you can be counted on to keep me honest.