# Changing \textheight in the middle of a LaTeX document

Tags: margins, height

Actually, I want to change `\textheight` only on one page of my document, then continue with the old dimension again. How can I update `\textheight` in my `.cls` file e.g. for my title page? Is there an easy way to change `\textheight` in the middle of a document? I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: don't change \textheight use `\enlargethispage{2cm}`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I use it with \pagebreak and it works :)

Comment: Related: [What happens when \textheight changes mid-document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48172/2417)

Answer (score 7):

Don't change `\textheight` : use

```
\enlargethispage{2cm}
```