# Change \textheight in function of width

Tags: macros, environments

Good day.
I want define an environment that change the text height in function of the width

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight

\newenvironment{whtext}[1]{%
\newpage\begingroup
\hsize=#1 
\vsize=\dimexpr\textheight*\numexpr\hsize/\textwidth\relax  
\textwidth=\hsize
\textheight=\vsize}%
{\endgroup\newpage}


\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{whtext}{15cm}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight
\lipsum[1-20]
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight
\end{whtext}

\end{document}
```

what i should do?

Comment: Do about what? What is your question?

Comment: How i can do this it doesn't work like this

Comment: how to define \vsize

Comment: Somewhat related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48172/what-happens-when-textheight-changes-mid-document

Comment: that doesn't help i need to change textheight in next page as geometry do but without it

Comment: I found an answer but i still look for better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an answer

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{whtext}[1]{%
\newpage\begingroup
\hsize=#1 
\vsize=\dimexpr\textheight*\hsize/\textwidth\relax  
\textwidth=\hsize
\textheight=\vsize}%
{\endgroup\newpage}
\makeatother

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{whtext}{15cm}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight
\lipsum[1-20]
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight
\end{whtext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to manipulate `textheight` etc. directly. The `geometry` package provides the means for doing this with `\newgeometry`, however, the price is a `\clearpage\newpage`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight

\newenvironment{whtext}[1]{%
\newpage\begingroup
\hsize=#1 
\vsize=\dimexpr\textheight*\numexpr\hsize/\textwidth\relax  
\newgeometry{textheight=\vsize,textwidth=\hsize}
 }%
{\endgroup\newpage}


\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{whtext}{15cm}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight

\lipsum[1-20]
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight
\end{whtext}

\begin{whtext}{10cm}
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight

\lipsum[1-20]
\the\textwidth---\the\textheight
\end{whtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i need no package