# How to adjust textwidth and textheight to paper size in mid document? (and header and footer "length" as well)

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I want to adjust textwidth and textheight to papersize in mid document, that simple.

I am planning to change some pages paper size, but I need both the header, footer and text to adjust (better if automatically) to the paper size.

I've been playing around with geometry package and I was unable to find an option that help me.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newlength{\classpageheight} \setlength{\classpageheight}{\pdfpageheight}
\newlength{\classpagewidth} \setlength{\classpagewidth}{\pdfpagewidth}

\lipsum[1-6]
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=17in \pdfpageheight=18in
\lipsum[1-6]

\eject \pdfpagewidth=\classpagewidth \pdfpageheight=\classpageheight
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[MWE compiled here](https://www.overleaf.com/2396753phczdy#/6204854/).

Comment: you can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226930/change-textheight-in-function-of-width maybe it help

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you for answering, I did so, but it didn't worked, can you please post the full answer?.

Comment: @touhami Thanks for answering. I did just took a look at that post and tried to implemented, but failed doing so, would you please help me getting that to work?.

Comment: @HarishKumar I did so, but it is still not working, I don't know if I didn't make myself clear. What I am trying to do is change the paper size, just for a couple of pages, to a large customize paper size, then be able to write all over the page without scaling the text and having the header all the way through the paper size as well. Please feel free to have a look to the link I provided in my question, the second page will make my question more explicit. Also feel free to ask, maybe I am not being clear in off.

Comment: @Hans Sorry I made a mistake in my last comment. → Remember that you can't change paper size midway though.  Read as `can't`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I am following the instructions shown in the accepted answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document

Comment: @Hans i was at work. i have a solution just give me some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution your remarks are welcome

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\def\vcoef#1{#1=\dimexpr #1*\pdfpageheight/\paperheight\relax}
\def\hcoef#1{#1=\dimexpr #1*\pdfpagewidth/\paperwidth\relax}

\makeatletter 
\def\adjustpagedim#1#2{%
\newpage
\pdfpagewidth=#1 \pdfpageheight=#2
\hcoef\textwidth
\vcoef\textheight
\vsize=\textheight
\@colroom=\textheight
\@colht=\textheight
\columnwidth=\textwidth
\if@twocolumn%
   \advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
   \divide\columnwidth\tw@%
   \@firstcolumntrue%
\fi%
\hsize=\columnwidth
\linewidth=\hsize
\hcoef\evensidemargin
\hcoef\oddsidemargin
\vcoef\topmargin
\vcoef\headheight
\vcoef\headsep
\vcoef\footskip
\hcoef\marginparwidth
\hcoef\marginparsep
\headwidth=\textwidth
% this is important but does nothing here
\paperwidth=\pdfpagewidth
\paperheight=\pdfpageheight}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
%----->I change something here
\newlength{\classpageheight} 
\setlength{\classpageheight}{\paperheight}
\newlength{\classpagewidth} 
\setlength{\classpagewidth}{\paperwidth}

\lipsum[1-6]

\adjustpagedim{17in}{18in}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-6]

\adjustpagedim{\classpagewidth}{\classpageheight}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe you need to adjust the \columnsep befor \iftwocolumn

Comment: Thanks sir, the output is just what I need, but I have two questions so far, How do I get it to work with two columns if the document was with two columns, and with one column? (maybe this is explained in the `\columnsep` advice, but I couldn't implement it), and How do I manually set the margins?. As you may notice, I've never toggled with code in LaTeX.

Comment: edit your question and add exemple with twocolumn to explain what you need

Comment: All right, cool.

Comment: Before the two columns thing, can you please tell me how do I customize the margins?.

Comment: you can for example try \adjustpagedim{17in}{18in}
 \evensidemargin=5cm
 \oddsidemargin=5cm
 \topmargin=10cm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22002/discussion-between-hans-and-touhami).